# How can I export reduced resolution RAW files from Lightroom?

Tags: software, lightroom, raw, rescaling, lightroom-4

I read that in Lightroom 4 is possible to export reduced resolution raw files.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Hi Ghigo. This is different from a typical web forum — please add your answer as an _answer_ rather than making it part of the question.

Comment: mattdm, thanks for the tip. This is exactly what I wanted to do but until i get 100 point I can't answer my own question before 8 hours.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, hopefully we'll see you back in a few more hours. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having done some research on the Adobe Lightroom help site I found this article on how to export to file.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS75C39DDC-B701-4840-A703-0755A5C04878.html

I believe the feature you are referencing to is to do with

**Enhanced DNG options**

- Resolution reduction via export provides the ability to share lower resolution versions of the original raw file without losing the capabilities offered by raw.

http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2012/01/lr4betanowavailable.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rob's links I found the solution.

Export the photo with the following settings:

- Image format: DNG
- Compatibility: Camera Raw 6.6 and later (required otherwise the lossy compression doesn't show)
- Use Lossy Compression: Checked

For a Canon 7D raw files this process reduce the size at about the 25% of the original. I think I just found a good solution for bringing my photos with me on my laptop while keeping the original raws on my desktop computer.